# undefined useState React after setting it to an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Goal: Fetch data from api then assign it to a state for further processing.

Issue: After setting the data to my useState it is still undefined.

Questions:

- How would one solve this problem?
- Am I misunderstanding the useState hook?

[image]

Comment: Your function is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import "./styles.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState();

  const functionz = () => {
    return axios
      .get("https://randomuser.me/api/")
      .then(({ data }) => data.results);
  };
  useEffect(async () => {
    const data = await functionz();
    setUserData(data);
  }, []);

  if (userData) {
    console.log(userData);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Edit to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You have to make sure your function is returning the axios call. Then await whatever comes out of it in your useEffect. Then proceed to adding it to your state. See example.

Comment: Thx, yeah, so basically the useEffect was running both functions not caring about the await since it was inside the fetchRandomUserData function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";

const Api = () => {
  const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState(null)

  const fetchRandomUserData = () => axios.get('the-url')

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRandomUserData()
      .then(resp => {
        setUsersData(resp.data.results)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('Error: ', e)
      })
  }, [])

  console.log(usersData)

  return <div></div>
}

export default Api
```